# How to solve this second order linear homogeneous ODE?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm trying to solve

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{2dy}{dt}+10y=0$

Initial values $t=0$, $y=1$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$, $h=\frac{1}{1000}$.

Problem: Find $y$ when $t=1$ using the [Heun Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun%27s_method) to approximate it.

First I try to calculate it exactly using math, then compare it to the python program I made. The results were different so I am not sure where I got lost.

This is how I did it using math.

Let $\frac{dy}{dt}=z$.

Then I get two equations

$\frac{dy}{dt}=z=f_1(t,y,z),y(0)=1$

$\frac{dz}{dt}=-2z-10y=f_2(t,y,z),z(0)=0$

Since $1y''+2y'+10y=0$ doesn't have real roots, I get this form

$y=e^{-t}(c_1cos(3t)+c_2sin(3t))$

From that I get two equations

$y=e^{-t}(c_1cos(3t)+c_2sin(3t))$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=-e^{-t}((c_2+3c_1)sin(3t)+(c_1-3c_2)cos(3t))$

If I sub in $y=1, t=0$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$, I get
$c_1=1, c_2=\frac{1}{3}$

Then if I solve for $y$ with $t=1$, $c_1=1, c_2=\frac{1}{3}$, I get ~$0.37$.

In my python program, I have:

```
def f1(t,y,z):
    return z
def f2(t,y,z):
    return -2*z - 10*y

t=0
y=1
z=0
h=1/1000.

while t<1:
    k1y=f1(t,y,z)
    k1z=f2(t,y,z)

    k2y=f1(t+h,y+h*k1y,z+h*k1z)
    k2z=f2(t+h,y+h*k1y,z+h*k1z)

    t+=h
    y+=h*0.5*(k1y+k2y)
    z+=h*0.5*(k1z+k2z)

print y
```

And it prints $-0.346891856552$

I would expect them to be pretty much the same number. Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The math part is ok: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2B2y%27%2B10y%3D0%2C++y%280%29%3D1%2C+y%27%280%29%3D0+

Comment: Thats the step size, for the python program.

Answer (score 1):

When you converted the 2nd order ODE into the equivalent 1st order system of two ODE's, you put a typo in the second equation. Where you wrote $\frac{dz}{dt}=-2z-y=f_2(t,y,z),z(0)=0$, you should actually have $\frac{dz}{dt}=-2z-\color{#ff0000}{10}y=f_2(t,y,z),z(0)=0$. You made the same omission in your python code.

Comment: Ok I changed the post to reflect this, but I still get the wrong value.... Output is negative.

Comment: The new program output is correct as it is approximately $e^{-1}\cos 3 + \frac{1}{3}e^{-1}\sin 3$.

Comment: If I do that, I get a positive value, but the program gives a negative value.

Comment: Check your units. The value is negative if you are working with radians. [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E-1+*+cos+3+%2B+%281%2F3%29*e%5E-1+*+sin+3)

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, check units where?

Comment: @omega If you are using a calculator to evaluate the exact answer, then you may be in Degree mode instead of Radian mode. This often leads to incorrect answers. Click the Wolfram link in my last comment.

Comment: I tried radian mode on calculator $\frac{1}{e}cos(\frac{3pi}{180})+\frac{1}{3e}sin(\frac{3pi}{180})$ and it gave the same positive answer...

Comment: Do the same calculation without the $\frac{\pi}{180}$ as the original problem was never in degrees to begin with.